# TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' based on id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

In my React app, I want to render different components based on id. Currently, I am doing this using a switch case. However, I want to pass different strings into the header based on which component is being rendered. I've created my steps object like this in App.js

** Example showing error **:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-otwg1l

```
function App() {
    const [intialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
  
    const steps = [
      {
        id: 'location',
        title: 'Select your store',
        nextStep: 'step 2',
        component: Comp1,
      },
      {
        id: 'questions',
        title: 'Answer Question',
        nextStep: 'step 3',
        component: Comp2,
      },
      {
        id: 'appointment',
        title: 'make and appointment',
        nextStep: 'step 4',
        component: Comp3,
      },
      {
        id: 'inputData',
        title: 'Add Data',
        nextStep: 'step 5',
        component: Comp4,
      },
      {
        id: 'summary',
        title: 'The End',
        nextStep: 'summary',
        component: Comp5,
      },
    ];
  
  
    return (
      <>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <SiteHeader />
          <div className="container">
            <ApptHeader steps={steps} />
            <Step steps={steps} />
          </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </>
    );
  }
  
  export default withRouter(App);
```

and I then pass `steps` into my Step.js component

```
import React from 'react'

import { useStep } from 'react-hooks-helper';

const Step = ({ steps }) => {
  const { step, navigation } = useStep({ initialStep: 0, steps });
  const { id } = step;
  const props = { navigation };

  const Component = steps[id].component;
  return <Component {...props} steps={steps} />;
};

export default Step;
```

However, when I try this, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of undefined` for this line of code: `const Component = steps[id].component;`

In AppJS, the console log for steps returns the following information:

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "location", title: "Select your store", nextStep: "step 2", component: ƒ}
1: {id: "questions", title: "Answer Question", nextStep: "step 3", component: ƒ}
2: {id: "appointment", title: "make and appointment", nextStep: "step 4", component: ƒ}
3: {id: "inputData", title: "Add Data", nextStep: "step 5", component: ƒ}
4: {id: "summary", title: "The End", nextStep: "summary", component: ƒ}
```

However, in the Step component, steps console log is `undefined` because the component does not render. What is causing this error with the `id` & what is the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Steps` is an array so you need to filter component like below:-

```
const Component = steps.find(innerStep => innerStep.id === id).component;
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Brother, try this. Hope this will help.

```
const { id, component: Component } = step;

return <Component {...props} steps={steps} />;
```

The problem is you are searching for an index in the `steps` array that matches with 'id'. But array has number type index like steps[0]. But here `id` is a string.